# Multiple hero-units to be the same height

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `<div>` with three `span4`s inside it, with a `hero-unit` inside each `span4`. Inside each hero unit is some text and a picture.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GGMWX/256/

And the code, in case that link breaks in the future:

```
<div class="row-fluid"> 
    <span class="span4">
        <div class="hero-unit" id="col1">
            <h1 class="heading">One</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x400/000/fff" class="image" />
        </div>
    </span>
    <span class="span4">
        <div class="hero-unit" id="col2">
            <h1 class="heading">Two</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </p>
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x200/000/fff" class="image" />
        </div>
    </span>
    <span class="span4">
        <div class="hero-unit" id="col3">
            <h1 class="heading">Three</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x200/000/fff" class="image" />
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to make all hero-units the same height. I have tried the following but none of them work for various reasons (some of them only work for text with no picture, one of them just works for plain text with no tags inside the outer div tag). Or perhaps I'm missing something -- I'm new to this.

http://tomdeater.com/jquery/equalize_columns/

http://jsfiddle.net/4HxVT/

http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/equalHeights/ and http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate the items once the document has loaded, get the tallest one, and then set them all to that height like so:

```
highest = null
hi = 0;
$(".hero-unit").each(function(){
    var h = $(this).height();
    if(h > hi){
        hi = h;
        highest = $(this);  
    }    
});
if(highest !== null){
    $('.hero-unit').css('height', highest[0].scrollHeight + "px");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GGMWX/261/

Comment: OK, the code works but now I expect if I change your code ".hero-unit" to "#equalize", and change my code's "col1"/"col2"/"col3" id attributes to all be id="equalize" that it would still work. But it doesn't. Basically I'm trying to iterate through the tags with id="equalize" rather than iterating through all the tags with class="hero-unit". That will enable me to have another hero-unit somewhere else on the page if desired. Why is this not working?

Comment: No, what you want is a custom class. ID's are called ID's for a reason, they are unique. Make your class "hero-unit equalize". The space in between is seperating the two classes on the attribute. This way it will be both a hero-unit and an equalize. Then in the javascript code (as above) to be `$(".equalize")` in both the spots.  Let me know if it still isn't working (perhaps with some jsfiddles)